# Wifi ERROR:When I start my Ubuntu(20.04LTS) the first time every day, the wifi logo and module can not be found

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

**Wifi ERROR**: When I start my Ubuntu(20.04LTS) the first time, the wifi logo and module can not be found. But when I restart my laptop, it usually can be fixed.
Do you have the same experience or know the way to solve it?
I hope you can help me. Many thanks!

Comment: Is it a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: yep, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my PC(windows 10), now it has two systems.

Comment: Disable Windows Fast Startup feature.

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes sense.